# How to delete a NTFS filesystem file whose name contains ":"?

Tags: filesystems, filenames, ntfs

I backup some of my Linux files in a NTFS removable hard disk several days ago, this time I need to remove those files. But I find it difficult since:

1. On windows, it complains that "*Could not find this item*"
2. On a virtual machine whose OS is ubuntu 12.04, when I mount the hard disk(I guess it's using "ntfs-3g") and use "`rm`", it complains "*No such file or directory*"; even "`ls`" fails for the file.

So are there any ways to smash this file correctly?

Comment: Run [`chkdsk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK) on Windows. It should fix filenames with invalid characters. The colon is normally used for alternate datastream, so maybe the question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14297/can-nix-handle-ntfs-ads-data-streams can help you.

Comment: @jofel works when using `chkdsk /f`, thanks!

Comment: As it has helped you, I converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run [`chkdsk /f`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK) on Windows. It should remove files with invalid characters or fix their filenames so that they can be removed manually.

Comment: Beware that for filenames that contain colons, the 'fix' is that the files are **deleted**.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams thanks for your comment, I clarified my answer. The real question is actually how to delete files with invalid filenames.

Comment: Unfortunately, from my testing, once files with colons have been created, chkdsk (and its forced deletion) are the only way to delete the files.

Answer (score 4):

NTFS supports "streams", like HFS+'s "forks" and unlike anything on the usual unix filesystems.

The convention on Windows is to name streams as part of the file name, separating the filename from the stream name with a `:`, which is why you were getting "could not find this item" -- for name "here: try this", Windows was looking  for stream " try this" in file "here".  I gather you can tell Windows not to parse filenames like this, but I don't know how.

ntfs-3g has a mount option to enable compatible stream-name parsing, mount the fs with `-o streams_interface=windows` and ntfs-3g will treat `:` the same way in filenames.  So to check for this, `mount|grep windows` should work well enough.

Answer (score 3):

If you've previously tried to run Windows chkdsk on an ntfs-3g filesystem containing colons but that was mounted and used under Linux without either the`windows_names` or `streams_interface=windows` option, the only way to restore NTFS filesystem integrity is to boot a Windows operating system and allow Windows `chkdsk` to permanently delete all files containing colons.

Put another way: be **very, very careful** running Windows `chkdsk` on an NTFS filesystem that has been written to using ntfs-3g under Linux.  **You will lose all files containing colons.**

There are two consequences of using ntfs-3g that interact to cause this:

1. Tuxera adheres to the letter of the NTFS spec, which allows colons in filenames.  However, there is virtually no one using filesystems that are exclusively non-Windows-compatible NTFS, and never intended to be used with Windows, so almost everyone actually needs the non-default behavior.
2. Tuxera's recommended failsafe way to repair a corrupted NTFS filesystem is to boot a Windows operating system, and run `chkdsk`.  (This will also happen automatically if you boot a Windows operating system and the filesystem is detected as needing repair.)

So if you are interested in long-term stability and safety of your filesystem, you will eventually need to boot a Windows OS and run `chkdsk` to repair it.  But when Windows `chkdsk` runs, it will delete all files with colons in their filenames **without any prompt or warning.**

Unfortunately, many folks use NTFS as a universal filesystem for portability and backups.  Two common files containing filenames in Linux are emails named after their subject line (Re:, Fwd:, etc.) and emails stored using the Maildir format.  So if you are creating an ntfs-3g filesystem from scratch for this purpose, make sure that you always mount it using the `windows_names` mount option and in `/etc/fstab`.  When you have to eventually run `chkdsk`, all files created on the filesystem should be valid.

If you don't do this, you may not be able to remove or salvage most or all of your Windows-invalid files (those containing colons, etc.).  Once you've created invalid files, Windows will consider the filesystem to be corrupt until those files are purged -- and only Windows will be able to repair the filesystem.  So repairing or deleting the files from Linux will be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

try `rm ./:`
or `rm ./":"`
or `rm ./\:` 
in  this order :)

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this is causing your problems. The following tests were run on an NTFS filesystem:

```
 $ mount| grep win
/dev/sda3 on /winblows type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
$ grep winb /etc/fstab
UUID=C0BCD19CBCD18D72   /winblows   ntfs    defaults    0   0
$ pwd
/winblows/foo
```

So, I am in an NTFS partition and I run:

```
$ touch :a a: a:b
$ ls
:a  a:  a:b
$ rm :a a: a:b
```

All of those commands work, anyway, possible workarounds are:

```
rm \:a
rm -- :a
rm ':a'
rm *:*
find . -name "*:*" -delete
```

Comment: I'm betting it's the `streams_interface` mount option: "By using the options "streams_interface=windows", with the ntfs-3g driver (not possible with lowntfs-3g), you will be able to read any named data streams, simply by specifying the stream's name after a colon. For example:

`cat some.mp3:artist`.
Named data streams act like normal files, so you can read from them, write to them and even delete them (using rm). You can list all the named data streams a file has by getting the "ntfs.streams.list" extended attribute."

Comment: @jthill yes, that sounds like the OP's issue, why not post an answer? Still, all of my suggested workarounds should work.

Answer (score -1):

Try archiving with winrar - select 'delete files after archiving' in the archiving options. 
This should move your files to the rar file and delete the original files. Then delete the rar file.