# "no such file or directory" message when deleting a file that exists on NTFS

Tags: files, rm, ntfs

I have a directory with images. Suddenly I found out that there's a new image with a new name. The image content is similar to another image in another directory but with a different name. I didn't copy this image to this directory.

Also a directory with the same name as the image suddenly appeared there. I didn't create any of them. When I tried to delete them I got this message "No such file or directory" even though it already existed there. I used the command `sudo rm -rf imagename.jpg` to delete it but it didn't work.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to solve it?

The output of `ls -l "large (2).jpg"`:

```
-rw------- 1 alaa alaa 2859942 Jun  8 04:01 large (2).jpg
```

The output of `rm "large (2).jpg"`:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘large (2).jpg’: No such file or directory
```

The output of `printf %s\\0\\n ./large* | sed -n l`

```
./large (20).jpg\000$
./large (26).jpg\000$
./large (2).jpg\000$
./large (5).jpg\000$
```

The filesystem is NTFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I once posted a [pretty in-depth look](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123732/52934) at NTFS *file-streams* as related to the linux `ntfs-3g` driver due to a similar issue on a different question. I remembered it, and -  guessing that your problem was also on an NTFS partition - I posted this comment here:

> If it's NTFS I suspect [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102043/how-to-delete-a-ntfs-filesystem-file-whose-name-contains). This can occur if a file's basic permissions are modified as you end up affecting the *stream*. I think that's what happens. It's complicated - and probably at least a little beyond me. But it happens. Anyway, run `chkdsk` in Windows.

Apparently, and happily, this has solved your issue.

Comment: I ran chkdsk utility in Win, but to no avail. The files are still there. I created them in Linux, and they contained ":" character, which is prohibited in Windows. What should I do?

Comment: @soshial - delete them. do it from your unix boot first. them reboot and chkdsk.

Comment: deleting with rm in linux gives me only "no such file or directory".

Comment: Be *very* careful running Microsoft's chkdsk after using NTFS from another OS like Linux. chkdsk will consider all filenames with colons that it finds as invalid, and *immediately* delete them without warning (rather than altering the filename and preserving the data). See my answer here for more info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128697/12947

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rm -i large*.jpg
```

This will ask you whether to delete every matching file. Say "no" for all the files other than this one.

Comment: same problem : no such file or directory!